# Samsung Galaxy Ace Debugging Mode not showing on Window 7

Tags: android, usb-debugging

I am facing a very strange problem on my mobile, I have turned on Debugging mode, but still when i try to connect it with laptop it is not showing any option, only it shows usb mass storage.

I am using Window 7 operating system and Mobile model is Samsung Galaxy Ace Duos

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is your phone rooted? Install SAMSUNG USB Drivers for Mobile Phones  http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1982287  your problem will be solved .

Comment: Thanks for giving me clue :)

Answer (score 0):

sounds like same issue as S3. try installing kies from samsung to install the drivers for it.